# JS - DOM and internal function

Tags: javascript, animation

So I have a code, which tries to make an animation but I have been facing failure since my first attempt.
Please help me, what's wrong with this code?

```js
function move(obj, x, y) {
    la = 20;
    while (la <= x) {
      obj.style.marginLeft += "20px";
      la = la + 20;
    }
}
move(document.getElementById("div"), 200, 200)
```

```html
<div id="div" style="border:1px solid black; width:100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS animation instead? While loops are not reliable for animation.

Comment: @Terry I need to execute this on function call

Comment: CSS animations can be activated by JS functions.

Comment: I run the code snippet and the can see the marginLeft += "20px" applied. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop will block UI of browser and all you see is jump. Make it async call with some delay.

Or better approach: use CSS animation and just toggle class:

```js
function move() {
  var element = document.getElementById("div");
  element.classList.toggle("moved");
}
```

```css
#div {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: margin 300ms ease-in-out;
  background: transparent;
}

#div.moved {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" onClick="move()"></div>
```